# Vue listen for Vuex commit?

Tags: npm, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

Is there a way to listen to a Vuex commit without watching any of the properties that are changed with the commit? Just simply finding out if a commit has happened?

I have a Filter component that I want to put into a NPM package but I already have a use case where I would want to set a cookie storing the filter preferences whenever a filter is selected.

Obviously it is not the responsibility of the filter component to set cookies etc. and this is something that should be optional.

I guess one way would be to use a global event bus but this would mean a user which uses my package would have to set one up exactly how I need it. Whenever the filter event gets fired a user could then perform necessary actions.

How do I keep this `SRP` and clean as an NPM package while still allowing a user to hook into certain events?

Kind of a broad question but I hope you get the gist.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can listen for commits/mutations using the store's `subscribe` method.

API Ref: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/api.html

Vuex plugins exist for this exact use case as well. Docs: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/plugins.html

Example:

```js
let vuexPlugin = (store) => {
    let whitelist = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'];
    store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {
        if (whitelist.includes(mutation.type)) {
            // your code here
        }
    });
};
```