# Listen to actions/mutations from within a vuex modules

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I have a vuex store with several modules, and I want to be able to listen to "global" `dispatch` or `commit` calls (aka actions and mutations) from within a module. For example, in an `auth` module there are actions like login and logout. Whenever those actions are dispatched, I want another module `ui` to also perform some action, like setting a language based on the logged in user.

I know I can just dispatch the `ui` actions from within the login and logout actions in the `auth` module. But I'd rather have it the other way around, so that `ui` is listening to the events (actions and/or mutations) dispatched in `auth`. This way I can easily create side effects without changing the "original" vuex module.

Maybe I need to use watches, but some actions don't alter state so I can't always use them. Creating a plugin is also an option, but I don't want to create an extra plugin each time I want to create such a side effect.

So my question; from within a vuex module, how can I listen to actions/mutations dispatched from other modules?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue listen for Vuex commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45132085/vue-listen-for-vuex-commit)

Comment: Maybe you can subscribe from within the module

Comment: thanks haven't found that one yet, but it suggests using a plugin. And I'm wondering if there is another way to listen to (or subscribe) to the actions in a module

Comment: I think a plugin would solve it for you

Comment: Using it as a plugin is optional. [Subscribe API](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#subscribe) can be registered on the store instance after it has been created. It is not possible to listen from within a module, since modules are compiled into a single store instance.

Answer (score 0):

I created a vuex plugin for myself which can will trigger all refresh action in all stores. But you can do anything else where I called the refresh.

Plugin:

```
const onModuleAValueChange= (store) => {
    store.watch(
        state => state.moduleA.value,
        (val, oldVal) => {
            // Don't do anything on init state
            if (!oldVal) return;

            // This will trigger all refresh actions on all store. But you can add anything here
            // Essentially does: 
            // store.dispatch(`moduleA/refresh`); 
            // store.dispatch(`moduleB/refresh`); 
            // store.dispatch(`moduleC/refresh`);
            for (let state in store.state) {
                const action = `${state}/refresh`;
                // If the store does not have an refresh action ignore
                if (store._actions[action]) store.dispatch(`${state}/refresh`);
            }

            // Additional action 
            store.dispatch(`moduleC/moduleC_Action`);
        }
    );
};
```

Store core:

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        moduleA,
        moduleB,
        moduleC
    },
    plugins: [onModuleAValueChange]
});
```